# Why can Tampermonkey still recognize variables prefixed with "window." in a sandbox environment without reporting an error?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

In theory, the following example script will be executed in the sandbox, so it should not be recognized. But why could it  close the window successfully without reporting an error?

In fact, I know that although it can run, it is only temporary. In an unsafewindow, any attempt to define the global variable of window obj will fail unless it is defined in an unsafewindow.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         temp
// @namespace    no
// @match        *:///*:/*/*
// @grant       unsafeWindow
// @grant window.close
// ==/UserScript==
window.close();
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"_

Answer (score 0):

`@grant` in userscript (in GM|TM|VM) refers to GM APIs that are especially made available to the userscript.

`@grant window.close` is supported by Tampermonkey & Violentmonkey and they map the `window.close()` function in the userscript to a background function to close the tab.

In other words, `window.close()` in VM|TM that run in the `content` scope is NOT the same as standard JavaScript `window.close()` that runs in `page` context.

Additionally, JavaScript `window.close()` can only close windows that have been opened by the script (requires `window.opener`) while the `window.close()` GM API can close the window (tab) even if it was not opened by the script.